# Cannot use angular ajax as it shows No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.But can use xmlhttprequest and jquery 3x to do it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

As the questions says, i used xmlhttprequest class and jquery ajax to load data from a server successfully.But i couldnt do it in angular ajax which says No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Note: Also when the jquery version is degraded to lower than 3 then it also shows No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' just like the angular ajax.Do they have any connection ???

Here is the jquery ajax code which is working but the same is not working when degrading the version from 3 to lower than 3:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $.ajax({
        url:'http://...',
        data:"{\"city\":\"Kolkata\"}",
        method:'post',
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json'},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And the next version is the normal xmlhttprequest version which is also working

```
$( window ).load(function() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "...";
var params = "{\"city\":\"Kolkata\"}";
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
//Send the proper header information along with the request

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
});
```

But angular1 ajax code is not working.The angular version is the latest one.

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '...',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded,application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json'},
        data: {'city':'Kolkata'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        //return response;
    },function errorCallback(response){
        //return response;
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think this is because jQuery sets the crossDomain  option to true if the request is cross-origin. They have CORS support built into the $.ajax functionality.

Comment: @Tom - although the client can do things to limit the triggering of CORS on a particular request (omitting headers etc.), once CORS is triggered it requires server side setting of response headers (cannot be handled solely by jQuery client). It is possible jQuery could be using jsonp to get around CORS.

Comment: @cchamberlain But i think that the headers are set on the server side.As jquery 3 as well as xmlhttprequest can successfullly access the data.So what i should i do in case of angular js? I need to use angular js.

Comment: You are setting different headers on the posts in your two examples, this is probably the reason why one is triggering CORS and the other is not. I don't think your server is setting CORS response headers based on your errors.

Comment: @cchamberlain Thank you very much cchamberlain :) . I changed Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded,application/json to just Content-Type': 'application/json and it is working. Again thank you very much.You saved my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is likely in your chrome devtools network tab. Take a look at the request and response headers for each of the requests, specifically for any CORS headers and the `Origin` header, looking for differences between the jQuery and Angular versions.

Also, see if there are any http requests of the `OPTIONS` method type, if so it is likely that the angular call is trying to send more headers or sending with credentials which would flag it for CORS.

If you cannot reduce the angular requests to not trigger CORS, you should be able to modify the server code to set a response header for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with a value of `*` or a string matching the origin that is being sent in request headers in most cases, although it really is dependent on the factors that are causing your request to use CORS. You may also need to supply `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header with value `*` or the names of the individual headers being sent in the request, comma separated.

It looks like your angular call is triggering CORS because you are setting an unsupported `Content-Type` simple request header:

[image: CORS Simple Requests]

Recommended reading - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS